# Logstash Jdbc Input plugin for MYSQL

Tags: jdbc, logstash

I am using Logstash in windows. i was not able to install input jdbc plug so i downloaded the zip file manually and place the logstash folder from plugin in to my logstash-1.5.2 folder.
the folder structure- "D:\elastic search\logstash-1.5.2\lib\logstash\inputs\jdbc.rb".

**my conf file**

```
input {
   jdbc {
     jdbc_driver_library => "D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar"
     jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
     jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    statement => "SELECT * from data"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
    jdbc_page_size => "50000"
   }
 }

output {  
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch { 
       embedded => true
       index => "bike"
       type => "bikeapp"
       cluster =>"trailcluster"
        protocol => "http"
       port => "9200"

    }
}
```

**when i run the logstash i get the error**

```
D:\elastic search\logstash-1.5.2\bin>logstash -f logtest.conf
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
←[33mjdbc plugin doesn't have a version. This plugin isn't well
 supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:warn}←[0m
←[33mYou are using a deprecated config setting "type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. You can achieve this same behavior with the new
 conditionals, like: `if [type] == "sometype" { elasticsearch { ... } }`. If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch --
->, :level=>:warn}←[0m
LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel
                  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1072
                  require at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65
  prepare_jdbc_connection at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:65
                 register at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:144
             start_inputs at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:148
                     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
             start_inputs at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:147
                      run at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:80
              synchronize at org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149
                      run at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:80
                  execute at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:150
                      run at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:91
                     call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
                      run at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:96
                     call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
               initialize at D:/elastic search/logstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.20/lib/stud/task.rb:12
```

Comment: Given the "deprecated" warning, you haven't posted your entire config.  Fix that problem obviously, but also notice "no such file to load -- sequel".

Comment: What i have mentioned above is the entire config file i have used. and what i should do to solve the "no such file to load  --sequel" error.

Comment: @VinothIlangovan, Hey are you install the `Jdbc` plugin to logstash

Answer (score 0):

After adding the Jar file to Plugin fodler,You just goto the folder path in `CMD Prompt` and install the plugin using below commands to logstash

**Run in an installed Logstash :**

Build your plugin gem

```
gem build logstash-input-jdbc.gemspec
```

Install the plugin from the Logstash home

```
bin/plugin install /your/local/plugin/logstash-input-jdbc.gem
```

Finally you will, Start Logstash and proceed to test the plugin using the configuration you are using....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it out.