# Copy index data from one ES index to ES another using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

could you please help to write a script, m getting the following error while running this script

```
input {
  # We read from the "old" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost" ]
    port => "9200"
    index => "products"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

output {
  # We write to the "new" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    port => "9200"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "%{[@metadata][_index1]}"
    index_type => "%{[@metadata][_type1]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
  # We print dots to see it in action
  stdout {
    codec => "dots"
  }
}
```

This is my logstash.conf file when I run this m getting the following error

Unknown setting 'port' for elasticsearch

```
{:level=>:error}
fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {\n  # We read from the \"old\" cluster\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [ \"localhost\" ]\n    port => \"9200\"\n    index => \"products\"\n    size => 500\n    scroll => \"5m\"\n    docinfo => true\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  # We write to the \"new\" cluster\n  elasticsearch {\n    host => \"localhost\"\n    port => \"9200\"\n    protocol => \"http\"\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][_index1]}\"\n    index_type => \"%{[@metadata][_type1]}\"\n    document_id => \"%{[@metadata][_id]}\"\n  }\n  # We print dots to see it in action\n  stdout {\n    codec => \"dots\"\n  }\
```

Comment: If you're using Logstash 2+, the port and index_type options are not valid anymore

Comment: yes I am  using 2.X version of log stash what is should do now.

Comment: Could you please let me know the correct format for 2.X version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the configuration, with the options of the 2+ version.

```
input {
  # We read from the "old" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "products"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

output {
  # We write to the "new" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][_index1]}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type1]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
  # We print dots to see it in action
  stdout {
    codec => "dots"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot baudsp ,but sorry to truble you again m getting the unwanted fields like

Comment: @PrasadKhandagale Glad I could help. To go from mysql to ES, you can use the [jdbc input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html).  You can find a few question on SO about this (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650623/elasticsearch-logstash-duplicating-output-when-use-schedule, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611171/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin-for-mysql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073928/logstash-jdbc-mysql-config-error). If it does not work, ask a new question, I don't have any experience with this input plugin.

Comment: Thanks Again bausap,it worked bu the mapping is not copied correctly in            "properties": {
          "text_field": {
            "type": "string",
            "index_analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }  this is the orginal mapping but the copied one does not contain this index & search analyzer                                                                             est_ktype": {
        "properties": {
          "text_field": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }

Comment: You'll have to delete your index, create an index with the mapping and reindex. The mappings are not part of the data, so they are not carried over to the new index